# DXT decompression - ressult differ +/- 1

Tags: opengl, textures

If I compress image using OpenGL (`GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT`) and then read back RAW image (OpenGL decompress it for me), I got certain image.

If I follow OpenGL documentation and write my own decompressor, my results are similar, but on certain places they randomly differ in terms of  +/- 1.
I have tried to round my values during "color blending" in DXT decompressor, but result is still incorrect.

Can it be repaired, or is it non-repairable error caused by GPU float arithmetic and therefor decompressed values are different.

Comment: are there any predictable patterns to where the +/-1 occurs? it may be a precision error as you say, but would need to look at the code to ascertain if it were a logic error or hardware likely error.  The implementation of DXT decompression varies dependant on GFX card, and I found a link [here](http://www.ludicon.com/castano/blog/2009/03/gpu-dxt-decompression/) which may help, and it has code for an example decompressor too.

Comment: @GMasucci No.. there is no pattern.. Article you´ve posted look good. Thanks. I think, you can add your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always I would look to see if there are any predictable patterns to where the +/-1 occurs? It may be a precision error as you say, but would need to look at the code to ascertain if it were a logic error or hardware likely error. The implementation of DXT decompression varies dependant on GFX card, and I found a link **[here](http://www.ludicon.com/castano/blog/2009/03/gpu-dxt-decompression/)** which may help, and it has code for an example decompressor too.

If you still get the error let me know and I can look at it overnight once I am at my home dev machine.

**Addendum:**
Just located the Intel resource I was looking for on DXT: it has a write-up **[here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-cpu-dxt-compression)** and source **[here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/samples/dxt-compression)**. ([direct link to source code in zip format](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/vcsource/files/45662/DXTCompressor.zip))